# Catch X11 XIO errors

Tags: docker, x11, glfw

I have an OpenGL / GLFW (which uses X11) app running inside a Docker container, starting when the PC starts. I have it installed on 2 differents PCs.

On the first one (an Intel NUC Enthusiast with an RTX 2060), everything works fine.

On the second one (a Dell Precision 7920 with a Quadro A6000), it crashes when starting on PC boot, but works fine when restarting it manually a bit later. The error is the following:

> XIO: fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server
> ":0" after 170 requests (170 known processed) with 0 events remaining.

It is triggered by a call to glfwPollEvents(); in my app's main loop. Seems my app is started a bit too early by Docker and that something is not started yet.

Then the app crashes with an exit code of 0, which me unable to workaround the problem using Docker's "on-failure" restart policy. Using the "always" policy works, but I'd prefer to avoid it.

So I'd like to catch this XIO exception, either to see if ignoring it for a while is enough, or to send a non-zero exit code so that Docker restarts the app until it works.

Is it possible? I have tried glfwSetErrorCallback & XSetErrorHandler, neither is called...

Comment: IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) is usually caused by a *programming bug* not an actual error. It means the socket was set to non-blocking and didn't block. If the program is expecting the socket to block then it must not set it to non-blocking. You should find out which bit of code raises this error and fix it. But it might be inside GLFW.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe too late, but still:

If you get an XIO error, maybe setting the appropriate error handler could be the right thing to do.

[XSetIOErrorHandler](https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/event-handling/protocol-errors/XSetIOErrorHandler.html)

> The XSetIOErrorHandler() sets the fatal I/O error handler. Xlib calls the program's supplied error handler if any sort of system call error occurs (for example, the connection to the server was lost). This is assumed to be a fatal condition, and the called routine should not return. If the I/O error handler does return, the client process exits.